# How to adjust size of Grecaptcha v2 iframe

Tags: javascript, css, html, checkbox, recaptcha

I am working with `recaptcha2`, when user checks the checkbox `iframe` rendered with images like fruits, cars etc. is too big for my need.

I want to customize height and width.

Can it be done in `V2`? Please suggest me some links if it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the element that the images are rendered in (the child element - table - of the div added on the DOM, by the "pls-container" class) and manipulate it using javascript, it seems to do the trick.

For example: for a single recaptcha, the following will reduce the element to 80% of the original size.

```
document.querySelector(".pls-container").style["transform"] = "scale(0.8)";
```

For multiples, you'd have to use querySelectAll() and loop through the resulting array.

This is possible because even though the recaptcha checkbox is in an iframe, the rendered images for selection are in your main DOM.